# Localization of header files iOS

Tags: iphone, xcode4

Is it possible to localize a header with macros in Xcode?

Lets say for English i might want a size of a font to be 17.0f, but 13.0f for Spanish.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. What I asked for is not possible. The header files are evaluated during build time but the localization is set during run time.

Comment: Interesting, I ran into this issue when I created a category on NSDate to give me a string with relative time from the date, example: 24 minutes ago, I needed this in spanish to I localised the .m file only, but the changes didn't take effect, it seems odd to allow the developer to localise these files in Xcode if it won't actually do so on the device as you might expect, but given the run time with a little reflection this seems logical. I will try to do as AliSoftware suggests http://stackoverflow.com/a/7321305/662605

Answer (score 2):

You can anyway put a PLIST file (let's say "constants.plist") in your .lproj localized folders (put the PLIST file aside you Localizable.strings files, in en.lproj/fr.lproj/es.lproj/...).

The PLIST may then contain an NSDictionary of key/value pairs for each value you need to customize according to the user locale (e.g. your font size).

Then you can use:

```
NSString* plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"constants" ofType:@"plist"]; // will return the path of the plist in the right language-specific .lproj directory)
NSDictionary* constants = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];

float fontSize = [[constants objectForKey:@"fontSize"] floatValue]; // or whatever key you use in your plist for this constant
```

This is then very easy to have a different constants.plist for each language of your app.

Comment: Great :) (If so, you may attribute the "solved" mark on my answer instead of your "it's not possible" own answer... :P)

Comment: It is the solution. However the question was "Is it possible to localize a header with macros in Xcode?". And I don't think your post answer that.